# pbcopy exits code 1, no error message

Tags: terminal, command-line, copy-paste, tmux

I'm trying to use `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to copy and paste to the clipboard from a shell. I read the man page to learn the syntax for these programs. However, no matter how I try to invoke `pbcopy` or `pbpaste`, they refuse to work, exiting code 1 with no error message. Command-C and Command-V work as normal.

```
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo foo | pbcopy                                                                                                                                          
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo $?                                                                                                                                                    
1
[jay-mba-osx ~]% pbcopy < foo.txt                                                                                                                                        
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo $?                                                                                                                                                    
1
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo foo | pbcopy -pboard general                                                                                                                          
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo $?                                                                                                                                                    
1
[jay-mba-osx ~]% pbcopy --help                                               
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo $?
1
[jay-mba-osx ~]% which pbcopy                                                                                                                                               
/usr/bin/pbcopy
[jay-mba-osx ~]% pbpaste                                                                                                                                                    
[jay-mba-osx ~]% echo $?                                                                                                                                                    
1
```

Any ideas why this is happening? It persists across reboots.

EDIT: OS X 10.9 Mavericks. Here is the result of `uname -a`:

```
Darwin jay-mba-osx.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

EDIT2: I have isolated this to occur *only* in tmux sessions. I didn't even think about that at first... now to figure out the *actual* problem...

Comment: Does `type pbcopy` also show it being in /usr/bin and is there any chance you have several OS installed / available or some off $PATH variable? Can we also presume you're in bash or have reproduced this with a stock shell (or something like `bash --rcfile /dev/null`)

Comment: Yes, `pbcopy` is `/usr/bin/pbcopy`. This was noted in my original question. ;) Yes, I have Windows and Debian Linux installed on this machine, but I don't see how that would have any effect...?

Comment: I've seen `which` fail people with oddball cases and `type` never has failed me under bash. You're probably in the clear with `which` but I wanted to rule some oddball edge case of a function or improperly hashed command out. I should have been more specific - older versions of OS X or darwin was all I was wondering in case you ran an incorrect version of `pbcopy`

Comment: I see what you're getting at. :) `command -v pbcopy` and `type pbcopy` both return `/usr/bin/pbcopy`.

Comment: Oh, no, OSX 10.9 (Mavericks). Sorry. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Didn't see your edit to your first comment, @bmike . I'm using `zsh`, but invoking `bash` without sourcing my rc file, as you suggested, results in identical behavior.

Comment: ok, I have at least isolated the problem: This happens *only* in tmux sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a problem with tmux detaching itself from the GUI namespace.

Fixed with: https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard